# Python, Prime number project

Tags: python, primes

I'm trying to create a program in python that asks for a number of prime numbers to print. The program should then print them ten at a line and then continue on the next line. I managed to solve the prime number bit, but I can't seem to find a solution to the ten at a line bit.

I would really appreciate the help

Input:

```
num = int(input("How many primes: "))
count = 0
prime = 2
while count < num:
    if all(prime%j!=0 for j in range(2, prime)):     
             print(prime, end =" ")
             count+=1
    prime +=1
```

> Output: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79
> 83 89 97 101 103 107 109 113 127 131 137 139 149 151 157 163 167 173
> 179 181 191 193 197 199 211 223 227 229

But I need this output
How many primes? 50

```
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29

31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71

73 79 83 89 97 101 103 107 109 113

127 131 137 139 149 151 157 163 167 173

179 181 191 193 197 199 211 223 227 229
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you could break a new line every time the remainder of count divided by 10 is 0 (count modulo 10)

Answer (score 2):

```
num = int(input("How many primes: "))
count = 0
prime = 2
while count < num:
    if all(prime % j != 0 for j in range(2, prime)):
        print(prime, end=" ")
        count += 1
        if(count%10 == 0):
          print("\n")
    prime += 1
```